# Python 3.6.2 emoji

Tags: python, исключения, utf-8

Доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
В python коде через aiohttp получаю json строку. Она в себе имеет emoji. При сравнение строки, которая отправлялась, и строки из json выходит исключение:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position
>   0-1: surrogates not allowed

сама строка, которая отправляется, выглядит так: `"\ud83e\udd16 Что я умею?"`

Как можно решить данную проблему?

P.S. сравнение выглядит таким образом:

```
message = await request.json()
if sendstr == message['text']:
   print('good')
   pass
```

Comment: покажите traceback Какой код у вас ошибку вызывает? Вы не должны видеть суррогатную пару после того как json распознался (`json.loads(r'"\ud83e\udd16"') == u'\U0001f916'  == u''` -- один символ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение в использование "\UXXXXXXXX" кодировки emoji символов или копипаст их на прямую в код

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте самой первой строкой в коде просисать:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: это не имеет отношения к проблеме. Декларация кодировки определяет кодировку исходного кода, которая никак не связано с тем как текст приходит в aiohttp сервер в виде json